# Using searchTwitter from TwitteR package in R API. I receive only 1 tweet, and I know there are more

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to retrieve tweets following certain keywords using RStudio and the twitteR package.

I have already successfully activated my developer account, and pasted my tokens and oath in my code.

The problem is I want to filter tweets that have the words "aragon", "carrera", and "montaña".

I got this code which works:

tweets <- searchTwitter("(aragon OR Aragon OR Aragón OR aragón) AND (carrera OR Carrera OR carreras OR Carreras) AND (Montaña OR Montana OR montaña OR Mountain OR mountain OR Montañas OR montañas)",n=150,lang="es")
tweets

and I obtain only 1 tweet.

If I just do this google search: "aragon" "carrera" "montaña" site twitter.com
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enES776ES776&biw=1536&bih=722&ei=Wo-sXMhAxd7AAsm4n5gP&q=%22aragon%22+%22carrera%22+%22monta%C3%B1a%22+site+twitter.com&oq=%22aragon%22+%22carrera%22+%22monta%C3%B1a%22+site+twitter.com&gs_l=psy-ab.12...4512.10793..12469...0.0..0.136.749.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz.8AXPsqgnZnA

I can see over 433.000 results.

Why is this happening? what can I do to retrieve a wider range of related tweets?